# XtrReports, xrPictureBox how to align Image to right ? Winform Devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

Am using Devexpress Winforms 12.2 version. I designed XtraReport with Logo on right side. When image is small automatically it align to left. I need to set pull right. Their is no option to set alignment in property. How to write programmatically code in BeforePrint event of xrPictureBox ?

I tried this one but didn't work `xrPictureBox1.Image = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;` showing error *cannot implicitly convert type ContentAlignment to Drawing.Image*

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better search their support channel, there are several threads on this subject, like [XTraReport - XRPictureBox alignment](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q398219) and [XRPictureBox - Provide the capability to specify image alignment](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S134710). From the last one looks like they finally provided out of the box solution [XRPictureBox.ImageAlignment Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXRPictureBox_ImageAlignmenttopic), but you need to upgrade to v15.1. If you can't, check if some of the suggested workarounds in the links work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried those links already i didn't get proper code to set alignment to right. Also I want to be in this version only 12.2.

Comment: @Srihari Yeah, that's bad. With DevExpress you should be updating constantly, otherwise you are stuck - their releases are full with bugs and incomplete features. I don't think you'll find a solution on SO, except someone is using same or lower version. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In a DevExpress report, you can center an `XRPictureBox` or align it by using the `LocationFloat` property and the `Report.Margins` property.

Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how to center an `XRPictureBox` control in a DevExpress report:

```cs
private void xrPictureBox1_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    // Calculate the X and Y coordinates to center the XRPictureBox control
    float x = (this.Report.PageWidth - this.Report.Margins.Left - this.Report.Margins.Right - this.xrPictureBox1.Width) / 2;
    float y = (this.Report.PageHeight - this.Report.Margins.Top - this.Report.Margins.Bottom - this.xrPictureBox1.Height) / 2;

    // Set the LocationFloat property of the XRPictureBox control to center it
    this.xrPictureBox1.LocationFloat = new DevExpress.Utils.PointFloat(x, y);
}
```

This code calculates the X and Y coordinates to center the `XRPictureBox` control by subtracting the left and right margins from the page width and the top and bottom margins from the page height. It then sets the `LocationFloat` property of the `XRPictureBox` control to center it. Finally, it assigns this code to the `BeforePrint` event of the `XRPictureBox` control in the designer or in code.

Comment: Hi, Hesham Yemen.  

Your two most recent answers over the last few days appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.